# What is provider string when configuring Linked Server

Tags: sql-server

I am configuring a linked server in SQL Server in order to send data from a SQL Server database to a MySQL database. While creating the linked server, in the fields to fill, I am asked the Provider string, unfortunately, I do not know what the Provider String is. Can somebody tell me what the Provider String is and how I can get it?

Here is a screenshot of the window where I need the Provider String

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Create Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15):

> #### Provider string
>
> Type the unique programmatic identifier (PROGID) of the OLE DB provider that corresponds to the data source. For examples of valid provider strings, see [sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

And then from that linked documentation:

> *[ @provstr = ] 'provider_string'*
> Is the OLE DB provider-specific connection string that identifies a unique data source. provider_string is nvarchar(4000), with a default of NULL. provstr is either passed to IDataInitialize or set as the DBPROP_INIT_PROVIDERSTRING property to initialize the OLE DB provider.
>
> ...
>
> ### Remarks
>
> The following table shows the ways that a linked server can be set up for data sources that can be accessed through OLE DB. A linked server can be set up more than one way for a particular data source; there can be more than one row for a data source type. This table also shows the sp_addlinkedserver parameter values to be used for setting up the linked server.
>
> | Remote OLE DB data source | OLE DB provider | product_name | provider_name | data_source | location | provider_string | catalog |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | SQL Server | Microsoft SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider | SQL Server 1 (default) |  |  |  |  |  |
> | SQL Server | Microsoft SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider |  | SQLNCLI | Network name of SQL Server (for default instance) |  |  | Database name (optional) |
> | SQL Server | Microsoft SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider |  | SQLNCLI | servername\instancename (for specific instance) |  |  | Database name (optional) |
> | Oracle, version 8 and later | Oracle Provider for OLE DB | Any | OraOLEDB.Oracle | Alias for the Oracle database |  |  |  |
> | Access/Jet | Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet | Any | Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 | Full path of Jet database file |  |  |  |
> | ODBC data source | Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC | Any | MSDASQL | System DSN of ODBC data source |  |  |  |
> | ODBC data source | Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC | Any | MSDASQL |  |  | ODBC connection string |  |
> | File system | Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Indexing Service | Any | MSIDXS | Indexing Service catalog name |  |  |  |
> | Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet | Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet | Any | Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 | Full path of Excel file |  | Excel 5.0 |  |
> | IBM DB2 Database | Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 | Any | DB2OLEDB |  |  | See Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 documentation. | Catalog name of DB2 |

So you can choose the appropriate value of the provider from the OLEDB source you are using for your linked server.